# finding a continuous extension

Tags: calculus

Define $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\cos x}{x}$ 
         $   f:\mathbb{R\backslash}\left\{ 0\right\} \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$

So I need to determine if there is a continuous extension to $f\left(x\right)$
  at a=0
  and then find it if so.

What I thought of is since ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^{-}}f\left(x\right)=-\infty}$
  and $ {\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^{+}}f\left(x\right)=\infty}$
 , then it's not possible that there is a continuous extension to $f\left(x\right)$

Is that argument valid?

Comment: Yes, you are right! This cases are called "essential singularities".

Comment: @emiliocba: I'm not sure what you mean.  Viewed as a function of a complex variable, $f$ has a pole at zero, not an essential singularity.  (Remember that on the Riemann sphere there is only one point at infinity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is valid.

In fact, even half of your argument is valid: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = \infty$ is already enough to see that $f$ cannot extend to a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to formalize that explantation, by intuition it's quite obvious why the function cannot be extend.

Comment: @sony jimbo: If $f$ could be defined at zero so as to be continuous, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ must exist.  But since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = \infty$, this limit does not exist.